# How to fix my code when mysql query dies, but query works in dbms?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to setting up a website for a school procjet, where I've to join to tables to get a result. When I insert the code in phpMyAdmin in runs and gives be the desired result, but in the php file it dies.

```
<?php

$database = conn

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

    alert ("Ingen kontakt med server.");

}

if (isset($_POST ["finnKlasse"])) {

    $klassekode=$_POST ["klassekode"];  
    $sqlSetning= "SELECT STUDENT.bildenr, STUDENT.fornavn, STUDENT.etternavn, BILDE.filnavn FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN BILDE ON STUDENT.bildenr=BILDE.bildenr WHERE STUDENT.klassekode=$klassekode;";
    $sqlResultat=mysqli_query($database,$sqlSetning) or die ("Errormessage");

    $rad=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlResultat); 

    print("$rad");

}
```

I now get the error message,

> whereas I would like a table output with STUDENT.bildenr,
>   STUDENT.fornavn, STUDENT.etternavn, BILDE.filnavn (it works in
>   phpMyAdmin).

Answer (score 1):

What error message are you getting ?
 Is $klassekode string ?
If it is change this

```
$sqlSetning= "SELECT STUDENT.bildenr, STUDENT.fornavn, STUDENT.etternavn, BILDE.filnavn FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN BILDE ON STUDENT.bildenr=BILDE.bildenr WHERE STUDENT.klassekode=$klassekode;";
```

To

```
$sqlSetning= "SELECT STUDENT.bildenr, STUDENT.fornavn, STUDENT.etternavn, BILDE.filnavn FROM STUDENT INNER JOIN BILDE ON STUDENT.bildenr=BILDE.bildenr WHERE STUDENT.klassekode='$klassekode'";<br>
```

**Important note: this is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please try to use prepared statements instead**
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thumbs up for the hint with using prepared statements! It is so important.